# Does there exists a function holomorphic in the unit disk and continuous in its closure that cannot be continued any further?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

Does there exists a function $f:\mathbb{\bar D}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that

(1) $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$ and $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{\bar D}$ where $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disk in the complex plane;

(2) for any $\delta>0$, $f$ has no analytic continuation to $B(0,1+\delta)$.

Since I cannot prove whether there is such a function or not, I tried some constructions. My first attempt was to construct a power series that has convergence radius $1$ and continuous in the closure of the unit disk. But my results so far have at least one singularity on the boundary. Then I tried to find an entire function with infinitely many zeros, and then identify its domain with the unit disk by a conformal equivalence, for example,

$$\sin\pi\frac{1-z}{1+z}$$

Then there is a convergence point of the zeros on the boundary. But the singularity problem still remains unsolved.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many such functions are known. One is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \eta_n z^{n}$ where $a_n=1$ if $n$ is a power of $2$, $0$ otherwise and $\eta_n=e^{-\sqrt n}$.  See 'natural boundary' in Rudin's RCA.  There are simpler examples for your question but in this example the function cannot be extended analytically **any open set** containing the closed unit disk.